# How can I detect keypresses even when window is running on background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I made this little autofarm bot for GT since I was bored, but problem is, that I don't have any way of stopping it other than Task Manager. So I was thinking, is there a way for my program to detect if any key is pressed down no matter what window is on foreground?

Here is the code I am using right now:

```
import pyautogui
import sys
from pynput.mouse import Controller
from sys import exit
from time import sleep
from msvcrt import getch
mouse = Controller()
move = int()
move = 0
collections = int()
collections = 0

input("Hover your mouse over FIRST BLOCK and press ENTER.")
b1 = mouse.position

input("Hover your mouse over SECOND BLOCK and press ENTER.")
b2 = mouse.position

input("Hover your mouse over PUNCH and press ENTER.")
p = mouse.position

input("Hover your mouse over COLLECT moving direction and press ENTER.")
c1 = mouse.position

input("Hover your mouse over RETURN moving direction and press ENTER.")
c2 = mouse.position


pt = float(input("Insert punch TIME (ftank 1.0; pepper 1.2; pball 2.6)"))




try:
    while True:
        pyautogui.click(b1)#Block 1
        pyautogui.dragTo(b2, duration = 0.25)#Block 2
        pyautogui.mouseDown(p)#Punch
        print("Punch Start.")
        sleep(pt)
        pyautogui.mouseUp()#Stop Punch
        move = move + 1 #Count loops
        print("Loop ", move, " Complete.")
        if move >= 150: #Gem Collection
            print("Collecting...")
            pyautogui.mouseDown(c1) #Collect Gems
            sleep(0.137)
            print("Finished.")
            pyautogui.mouseDown(c2) #Return to original position
            sleep(0.8)
            pyautogui.mouseUp()#Stop Moving
            move = 0 #Reset Counter
            collections  = collections + 1
            print("Finished ", collections,". Collecting Loop.")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You mean like a key logger?

Comment: No, I need it to detect if I hit any key, no matter which window is on foreground.